# Finding connection information for federated tables

Tags: mysql, federated

I have a couple of tables with federated storage engine (mysql). But I need to find the connection info for those two tables. Desc command is not helpful. I don't see the table mysql.servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took mysqldump without data, just with ddl's of tables. There I found the connection information.